# Mathematica doesn't evaluate my Limit expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, periodic-function

I tried to evaluate the following limit:

```
Limit[Sin[x]^n, n -> Infinity]
```

However, Mathematica doesn't evaluate it, and just reprints the original problem:

> ```
> Limit[Sin[x]^n, n -> ∞].
> ```

I was expecting as result a function that oscillates between 0 and 1.

Comment: How would you represent such a function in Mathematica?

Comment: I guess: 
value: 1 when x = 2kPi+Pi/2, with k=0,1,2,3...
and value: 0? otherwise.

Comment: Not in words, but  in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be assuming in your mind that `n` is an integer and `x` is real, but Mathematica makes no such assumption by default. If you were to make these assumptions explicit you will get a result.

```
Limit[Sin[x]^n, n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && x ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[0, Log[Sin[x]] < 0]
> ```

That is not the answer as you conceived it, but it is not unreasonable.

Comment: The condition can be expressed also as the output of `Reduce[Log[Sin[x]] < 0, x, Reals]`